# What is the forensic procedure in investigating DDoS attacks

Tags: forensics, ddos

I'm currently in the process of researching for an assignment. In this assignment, I am asked to produce reports on new crimes enabled by technology and how, in Cyber Forensics, one would investigate said crimes.

I am having great difficulty finding information on how one would go about investigating DDoS attacks. The only realistic ideas I can produce would be using the networks logs of the victim of a DDoS attack to identify bots, then collaborating with the ISP providing the victim's internet to identify the location of these bots on the internet. However, I feel this to be lacking substance if I ever put this in my assignment.

What forensic procedures are used in investigating thoroughly perpetrators of DDoS attacks? How does one discover the origin of these attacks and, ergo, the criminal who committed said act?

Comment: You are likely not going to trace the perpetrator as the victim. You can identify the sending nodes of the offending traffic by looking at traffic logs. You would need access to the bot nodes and perform forensics on those in order to trace what sent commands to the node, and so on and so on until you reach the originating node. And then you can use forensics to identify the user of that node.